# R storing models by an index

Tags: r

Using the package **earth**, I have a number of models and I would like to call a model up by its index number.

I have tried using a list but this does not work.

```
a <- list(a)
a[1] <- earth(Volume ~ ., data = trees1)
a[2] <- earth(Volume ~ ., data = trees2)
a[3] <- earth(Volume ~ ., data = trees3)
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a <- list(a)
a[[1]] <- earth(Volume ~ ., data = trees1)
a[[2]] <- earth(Volume ~ ., data = trees2)
a[[3]] <- earth(Volume ~ ., data = trees3)
```

You will generally want to access the contents with "[[" as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
 x<-1:5
 y<-1:5
 a<-lm(x~y)
 b<-lm(y~x)
 mylist<-list(a,b)
 mylist
```